# с++ Не могу понять код с битовым оператором ИЛИ (исключительное): ^

Tags: c++

```
void Permutations(int items [], int size, int l=0)
{
    int i;
    if (l == size){
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
          printf("%d ", items[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    else
        for (i = l; i < size; i++)
            {
            if (l ^ i)
                {
                 items[l] ^= items[i];
                 items[i] ^= items[l];
                 items[l] ^= items[i];
                 Permutations(items, size, l + 1);
                 items[l] ^= items[i];
                 items[i] ^= items[l];
                 items[l] ^= items[i];
                }
            else
                 Permutations(items, size, l + 1);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю, вам непонятно, что именно делает тут код с `^`? Это по сути код обмена значений. Как работает `^`, надеюсь, вы знаете - побитово, дает 0 при совпадении операндов, и 1 - при разных операндах.

Так что рассмотрим пример

```
                 a              b
              01010101     00110011
a ^= b        01100110     00110011
b ^= a        01100110     01010101     
a ^= b        00110011     01010101
```

Как видите, все просто :)

Comment: я бы ещё добавил, что лучше используйте `swap()` он и быстрее и читабельнее.

Comment: "Всё просто": верно ли что для int это к "undefined behavior" не ведёт? Возможно ли создание "negative zero"/"trap representation"?

Comment: @jfs вроде бы нет. В стандарте нету же ограничений на использование операции ^. Чисто в теории, мы можем получить не тот результат которой ожидали (если после использования ^ произойдёт "нормализация"), но UB не будет.

Comment: @jfs Не должно - операция всегда дает представимое число. Для большего спокойствия можно использовать `unsigned int`...

Comment: Для C++ не смотрел, а для C есть такие слова: *"[it] is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1
and all value bits zero ... is a trap representation or a normal value."* и *"If the implementation does not support negative zeros, the behavior of the `&, |, ^, ~, <<,`
and `>>` operators with operands that would produce such a value is undefined."*

Comment: @jfs Значит, надо с приведением к `unsigned` работать. Но в любом случае "это не наш метод" (с) :)